# Javascript ScrollToView of Empty Textbox Not working - Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll

When ever there is value in the textbox, scroll works, otherwise doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.NavigationDiv input[type="text"],textarea').keyup(function (e) {

    var x = parseInt($(this).attr("x"));
    var y = parseInt($(this).attr("y"));
    debugger;
    if (e.which == 39) {
        var element = $(".NavigationDiv").find('[target=' + x + '-' + (y + 1) + ']');
        element.select();
        $(element).scrollIntoView();
    } else if (e.which == 37) {
        var element = $(".NavigationDiv").find('[target=' + x + '-' + (y - 1) + ']');
        element.select();
        $(element).scrollIntoView();

    } else if (e.which == 40) {
        var element = $(".NavigationDiv").find('[target=' + (x + 1) + '-' + (y) + ']');
        element.select();
        $(element).scrollIntoView();
    } else if (e.which == 38) {
        var element = $(".NavigationDiv").find('[target=' + (x - 1) + '-' + (y) + ']');
        element.select();
        $(element).scrollIntoView();
    }
});
```

});

[image]